# Markdown with knitr run two sets of code in one compiling

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

I have a question.

I am building a html file using R studio Markdown.

In my markdown file, I hope to divided the R code into two paragraphs, and run respectively.

````
```{r  cache=TRUE, echo=TRUE, include=FALSE}
require(maps)

```
````

Now I am going to run the other set of code.

````
```{r}
japan <- map("world", "japan", plot=T)
```
````

However, the second code can't be run because the R didn't load maps package.

Is there any way to save the first code result and pass it to the second code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you use `cache=TRUE` on the first chunk? That is where the problem comes from. When you turn on cache, remember that chunk will be skipped the next time you compile the document, and that means `require(maps)` will not be executed.

`knitr` does try to preserve *side effects* like loading packages ([see documentation](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/cache/)), but that works only for cached chunks. If you load a package in a cached chunk, but use it in an uncached chunk, it is not going to work. To sum up,

1. either do not use cache
2. or use cache consistently

Cache is very tricky. Be sure to read the documentation thoroughly before putting it into production.